# Centering model pivot

Tags: rigging

I have my model that is not centered and I don'[t know how to fix this because is the first time that I see something like this.. anyone have some idea to how fix this?

I have put it back to 0,0,0 but this is the result, since it's not my model but one that I downloaded from Unity Asset store I'm not the author of this.

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be succinct, unique and identifying, and summarize what the issue is so that users can at a glance broadly understand what your post is about before opening it. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid any emojis salutations or extraneous text not essential to the question. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and will weight heavily on their decision to open your question, which will directly affect the number of answers you might get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select your model in object mode. right click. select “geometry to origin”. that should move model to the center of grid origin and set model origin to center of model.